# How to get selected text from AccessibilityNodeInfo

Tags: android, accessibilityservice

I have a accessibility service running for event type "typeViewTextSelectionChanged". I am able to catch this event trigger whenever user selects any text, but how do I get the selected text content from **AccessibilityNodeInfo** or **AccessibilityEvent** objects

Answer (score 1):

The following goes inside,

```
onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event){}
```

And then,

```
//Get the source
AccessibilityNodeInfo source = event.getSource();

//Grab the parent of the view that fired the event.
AccessibilityNodeInfo rowNode = getListItemNodeInfo(source);

//Using this parent, get references to child node, the selected text
AccessibilityNodeInfo textNode = rowNode.getChild(0);

//Get the text values
String text = textNode.getText();
```

**OR**

Alternatively in your case, the following should work just fine. Since, it's a "typeViewTextSelectionChanged" event, it's obviously from an EditText.

```
String text=event.getText();
```

For more info, have a look [here](https://developer.android.com/training/accessibility/service.html) and [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityEvent.html)

Comment: I can't seem to find any documentation for getListItemNodeInfo, could you please link to where you seen that?

Comment: getListItemNodeInfo is a method from here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/accessibility/TaskBackService.java